# regular exp not working in IE

Tags: javascript

```
questionText.replace(/\d+/g,"");
```

is not working in IE ?

Comment: Isn't it?  That's interesting.

Comment: @Andrew : ya its not working in IE 7

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you showed us what questionText is, and give a bit more code to show what you're doing with that line.  It might also be helpful if you described what you're trying to do.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific than that. What does "not working" mean? What is `questionText`? In what context are you running this line of code?

Comment: sorry , it not regular expression its .textContent is not working

Comment: @kiran: Right, I suggest we kill this question and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you assigning the resulting string to anything?

```
var newQuestionText = questionText.replace(/\d+/g,""); 
alert(newQuestionText);
```